# R: Add a new variable to dataframes whose value is equal to the name of the dataframes

Tags: r, variables, conditional-statements

I want to add a variable to ALL dataframes in my global environment and make the value of the newly added column equal to the dataframe name.

```
Product=c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C")
Day=c("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Saturday","Sunday" ,"Monday")

data1=data.frame(Product, Day)

Product2=c("Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Y","Y","Y","X","X","X")
Day2=c("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Saturday","Sunday" ,"Monday")

data2=data.frame(Product2, Day2)
```

I want to add a column in both dataframes whose value is equal to the dataframe name, i.e newvar="data1" for data1 and newvar="data2" for data2. My actual data frame list is much longer than this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a function, where you can pass any arbitrary number of named data.frames, and it will return a list of named data.frames back with the requested column added. Using the `list2env` function (as in @akrun's answer) you can then put these in whatever environment you want. (You could also modify the function to produce that side-effect automatically.)

```
f <- function(...) {
    objnames <- as.character(substitute(c(...)))[-1]
    obj <- list(...)
    out <- mapply(function(x, col) {
        x[, col] <- col
        x
    }, obj, objnames, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
    setNames(out, objnames)
}
```

Here's how to use it:

```
list2env(f(data1,data2), .GlobalEnv)
# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
str(data1)
# 'data.frame':   18 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ Product: Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  $ Day    : Factor w/ 7 levels "Friday","Monday",..: 2 6 7 5 1 3 2 6 7 5 ...
#  $ data1  : chr  "data1" "data1" "data1" "data1" ...
str(data2)
# 'data.frame':   18 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ Product2: Factor w/ 3 levels "X","Y","Z": 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
#  $ Day2    : Factor w/ 7 levels "Friday","Monday",..: 2 6 7 5 1 3 2 6 7 5 ...
#  $ data2   : chr  "data2" "data2" "data2" "data2" ...
```

If you had a large number of named objects that you wanted to pass without listing them explicitly in `f()`, you could do something like:

```
list2env(do.call(f, sapply(ls(pattern = "data"), as.name)), .GlobalEnv)
```

which would have the same result.

Answer (score 2):

If the 'data.frame' object names are 'data' followed by number, we can either use `paste` to get the object names as a string (if we already know the object names)

```
  nm1 <- paste0('data', 1:2)
```

Or another option would be to use `ls` with the pattern argument if there are 100's of object names in the global environment and we don't know how many objects are present.

```
  nm1 <- ls(pattern='^data\\d+')
```

Get the values in a `list` using `mget`, and create a new column ('newvar') by `cbind`ing with `Map`.  Using `Map` make sure that each dataset in the `list` is added with a new column corresponding to the object names.

```
  lst <- Map(cbind, mget(nm1), newvar= nm1)
```

It is better to keep it in a `list` as it can do all the operations within it.  But, if the original object needs to be updated in the global environment, `list2env` is a an option (not recommended though)

```
  list2env(lst, envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

I may be also useful to read all the files (`.csv/.txt`) in a `list` directly rather than creating individual objects.  For example, we can read all the files in the working directory by

```
   files <- list.files()
   lst <- lapply(files, read.csv, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

The arguments may need some changes according to the delimiter.