# R: add a new column to dataframes from a function

Tags: r, function, dataframe, tibble

I have many tibbles similar to this:

```
dftest_tw <- structure(list(text = c("RT @BitMEXdotcom: A new high: US$500M turnover in the last 24 hours, over 80% of it on $XBTUSD. Congrats to the team and thank you to our u…", 
"RT @Crowd_indicator: Thank you for this nice video, @Nicholas_Merten", 
"RT @Crowd_indicator: Review of #Cindicator by DataDash: t.co/D0da3u5y3V"
), Tweet.id = c("896858423521837057", "896858275689398272", "896858135314538497"
), created.date = structure(c(17391, 17391, 17391), class = "Date"), 
    created.week = c(33, 33, 33)), .Names = c("text", "Tweet.id", 
"created.date", "created.week"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

For testing, we add another one:

```
dftest2_tw <- dftest_tw
```

I have this list of my df:

```
myUserList <- ls(,pattern = "_tw")
```

What I am looking to do is:

1- add a new column named `Twitter.name`

2- fill the column with the df *name*, all this in a function. The following code works for each df taken one by one:

```
dftest_tw %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(Twitter.name = myUserList[1])
```

The desired result is this:

```
MyRes <- structure(list(text = c("RT @BitMEXdotcom: A new high: US$500M turnover in the last 24 hours, over 80% of it on $XBTUSD. Congrats to the team and thank you to our u…", 
"RT @Crowd_indicator: Thank you for this nice video, @Nicholas_Merten", 
"RT @Crowd_indicator: Review of #Cindicator by DataDash: t.co/D0da3u5y3V"
), Tweet.id = c("896858423521837057", "896858275689398272", "896858135314538497"
), created.date = structure(c(17391, 17391, 17391), class = "Date"), 
    created.week = c(33, 33, 33), retweet = c(0, 0, 0), custom = c(0, 
    0, 0), Twitter.name = c("dftest_tw", "dftest_tw", "dftest_tw"
    )), .Names = c("text", "Tweet.id", "created.date", "created.week", 
"retweet", "custom", "Twitter.name"), class = c("rowwise_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

When it comes to write a function to be thereafter been applied to all my df (more than 100), I can't achieve it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have been following this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31754693/r-add-a-new-variable-to-dataframes-whose-value-is-equal-to-the-name-of-the-data , but I can't get a result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `tidyverse` options.  Get the value of multiple string objects with `mget`, then with `map2` from `purrr`, create the new column 'Twitter.name in each dataset of the `list` with corresponding string element of 'myUserList`

```
library(tidyverse) 
lst <- mget(myUserList) %>% 
          map2(myUserList,  ~mutate(.data = .x, Twitter.name = .y))
```

If we need to modify the objects in the global environment, use `list2env`

```
list2env(lst, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: this code will print the result on my screen, but the original df didn't change in my workspace.

Comment: @gabx  It is easy to do that.  But I would keep this in a `list` instead of creating objects in the global environment.  Modified the answer

Comment: exactly the solution I was looking for. Thank you so much

Comment: I am looking to save our results with another name, say adding ".final" at the end. This is to have a new list. This doesn't work: assign(paste(myUserList, ".final", sep = ""), myUserList). Any solution?

Comment: @gabx If that is the case, change the names of the `lst` with `names(lst) <- paste0(names(lst), ".final")` and then use the `list2env`

Comment: @gabx  Please check if you have the same structure as in the sample i.e. `str(yourrealdata)`